# Allow browser scrollbar to work with jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using a jquery dialog with `modal: true` by design disables interaction with other elements on a page - including browser scroll bar (at least in Chrome). How can I sidestep this intended limitation for my specific use case, for example if a dialog has `height:1000`.

*To be clear*: I am well aware that I can add an `overflow:auto` scrollbar to my div, but this is not what I want to do. I am looking to override the jquery modal default that turns off interaction with just the browser scrollbar!

```
$("#your-dialog-id").dialog({autoOpen:true,modal: true, height:1000});
```

Example showing scrollbar inoperative (in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/GKfZM/139/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a bug in Webkit (or jQuery UI, depending on who you'd like to blame).

jQuery UI bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4671

Webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19033

There's a patch for jQuery UI included in the bug, but it's not in UI trunk yet. This means modifying jQuery UI if you want to go that route.

Best of luck!

Comment: +1 dang, I was hoping there was some obscure property or something. I'll accept this answer in T-minus 5 minutes or so